# Cannot find name 'require' templateUrl

Tags: angular

While loading the page, getting error as cannot find require, in the line where I used templateUrl, but the system is very much stable, don't know where is exactly the error is occuring..

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Title}     from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

Comment: I am getting the same thing. Just started using the Angular CLI on a new project, and when I do `ng serve` I get the same error `Cannot find name 'require'` for all the components template urls and style urls...

Comment: The app works, though, it's just the annoying error message when building and in the console log...

Answer (score 3):

You're using Typescript, the Typescript Compiler type-checks everything you compile for you to see if it can help pop out some errors for you.
The error you're getting is Typescript letting you know it doesn't recognize the `require` function.
The application runs fine because it is still eventually available at runtime and thus the error you're getting is merely a "warning" from the Typescript Compiler.

To fix this you'll have to "teach" Typescript about functions such as `require`,
you can do that by installing nodejs types by running:

`npm install --save @types/node`

(You'd optionally need to add the following to your `tsconfig.json` so it loads types from `node_modules/@types`:

`"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types"
],`)

Comment: I just did this did not help, still getting the error warnings. Maybe I need to do something else, perhaps in addition, for example with tsconfig.json?

Comment: Try adding this to `tsconfig.json`:

Comment: `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],`

Comment: It worked when I added this to `tsconfig.json`: `"types": [ "node" ]`. Thanks, Amit!